# What is the best way to read large file (>2GB) (Text file contains ethernet data) and access the data randomly by different parameters?

Tags: c++, performance, file, large-files, random-access

I have a text file which looks like below:

```
0.001 ETH Rx 1 1 0 B45678810000000000000000AF0000 555
0.002 ETH Rx 1 1 0 B45678810000000000000000AF 23
0.003 ETH Rx 1 1 0 B45678810000000000000000AF156500
0.004 ETH Rx 1 1 0 B45678810000000000000000AF00000000635254
```

I need a way to read this file and form a structure and send it to client application.

Currently, I can do this with the help of circular queue by Boost.

The need here is to access different data at different time.

Ex: If I want to access data at **0.03sec** while I am currently at **100sec**, how can I do this in a best way instead of having file pointer track, or saving whole file to a memory which causes performance bottleneck? (Considering I have a file of size **2 GB** with the above kind of data)

Comment: use a database.

Comment: Hi @HongOoi, using database is fine. How can I access data randomly?

Comment: You could do a binary search.

Comment: In this example every line has exactly same byte length and first column is well defined arithmetic chain. If this is true for all lines then jumping between lines is quite easy.

Comment: hi @MarekR the the file may contains different byte length for each line

Comment: Hi @HongOoi, doing binary search every time is not feasible if we are considering performance. It should be somethink like, offset adjusting and retrieve the data immediatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

1. Used Circular buffers (Boost lock free Buffers) for parsing file and to save the structured format of line
2. Used Separate threads:

   - One will continuously parse the file and push to lock free queue
   - One will continuously read from the buffer, process the line, form a structure and push to another queue
   - Whenever user needs random data, based on time, I will move the file pointer to particular line and read only the particular line.
3. Both threads have mutex wait mechanisms to stop parsing once the predefined buffer limit reached
4. User will get data at any time, and no need of storing the complete file contents. As and when the frame is read, I will be deleting the frame from queue. So file size doesn't matter. Parallel threads which fills the buffers allows to not spend time on reading file every time.
5. If I want to move to other line, move file pointer, wipe off existing data, start threads again.

**Note:**
Only issue is now to move the file pointer to particular line. 
I need to parse line by line till I reach the point.

If there exist any solution to move file pointer to required line it would be helpful. Binary search or any efficient search algorithm can be used and will get what I want.

***I appreciate if anybody gives solution for the above new issue!***

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best practice for handling large files depends on the platform architecture (x86/x64) and OS (Windows/Linux etc.)

Since you mentioned boost, have you considered using boost memory mapped file?
[Boost Memory Mapped File](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html)

Comment: Hi Surya, Thanks for the info. I wanted to use it on both windows and linux. And if I use Boost Memory Mapped file, how can I access data randomly? and if the file size increases, the performance may decrease in this case

Comment: Boost Memory Mapped file is both Windows and POSIX compliant. 
using data() and the size_of_record * number of records to seek you can perform random access. Look-up `new_location = data() + (size_of_record * number_of_records)` and store the new_location like a pointer to the record.
The performance is only impacted when a page fault occurs so not a significant degradation when compared to the other large file reading methods.

Comment: Hi Surya, Thank you. I will try this and see the performance. By the way any idea on hdf5 library?

Comment: Number of bytes in each line is different. Each frame may contain variable length of data. In this case, getting new location data is not possible right?

Answer (score 0):

Its all depends on

- a. how frequently the data access is
- b. what pattern the data access is

  1. **Splitting the file**
     If you need to access the data once in a while then this 2GB log
     design is fine, if not the logger can be tuned to generate log with
     periodic interval/ latter a logic can split the 2GB files into needed fashion of 
     smaller files. So that fetching the ranged log file and then reading
     the log data and then sort out the needed lines is easier since file
     read bytes will be reduced here.
  2. **Cache**
     For very frequent data access, for faster response maintaining cache is one the nice solution, again as you said it has its own bottleneck. The size and pattern of the cache memory selection is all depends on the b. what pattern of data access is. Also greater the cache size also slower the response, it should be optimum.
  3. **Database**
     If the searching pattern is un-ordered/dynamically grown on usage then data-base will work. Again here it will not give faster response like small cache.
  4. A mix of database with perfect table organization to support the type of query + smaller cache layer will give optimum result.

Comment: Hi @Praveen, thanks for the info. If I use Database in this case, again the performance bottleneck occurs due to multiple query execution. Reading of data will happen every 5/10/20ms once. So is it okay to use database in this case?

Comment: I think a proper db design (mix of tables with proper fields) according to your types of queries will do the work.

:- As I said earlier "what pattern the data access is" is matters here,  I think depends upon the pattern we may optimize the search query. if the pattern is predictable then we may have a small cache so that frequent data pull from db will be minimized. 
I mean for example, if the upcoming 100 queries will be within a particular range of data, then we may have that particular range of data in cache (this is what I mean to say in above #4) 

let us know any better solutions.